How to prevent a popup menu from activating the application?
The popup menu is created in the dialog's WM_INITDIALOG message with this code:
HMENU hMenu = LoadMenu(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_POPUPMENU));
HMENU hMenuPopup = GetSubMenu(hMenu, 0);

and is invoked with this code:
TrackPopupMenu(hMenuPopup, TPM_RIGHTALIGN | TPM_VCENTERALIGN, xpos, ypos, 0, hwnd, NULL);

This activates the application whose main form is a no-activate dialog created from a resource with this code:
hwndDialog = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), nullptr, DialogProc);
ShowWindow(hwndDialog, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);

How to prevent the menu from activating the application?

SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE merely controls the behavior of the ShowWindow() call. It will not turn the dialog perpetually non-activatable. For that, you would need to handle the WM_MOUSEACTIVATE message and respond with one of the MA_NOACTIVATE constants.

@IInspectable Returning MA_NOACTIVATE on dialog's WM_MOUSEACTIVATE does not fix the problem as the application seems to be activated whenever a call to TrackPopupMenu is made.

How about not calling TrackPopupMenu in the dialog's WM_INITDIALOG message?

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT It is not called on WM_INITDIALOG message. It is called in winMain, after the creation of the dialog, and also on a button click. Whenever it is called, it activates the application, which does not happen when, for example, a button on a form is clicked.

Does TrackPopupMenu() activate the owner window, or does it merely bring it to the top of the Z-order? Z-order and window activation are distinct concepts.

@IInspectable The external process that previously held the focus/cursor, looses the focus/becomes inactive. The GetTopWindow(hwndDlg)  does not return NULL after the menu is shown but does return NULL  in all other code (on button clicks, for example).

@IInspectable I think you might be right about the Z order numbers.

It could be by design otherwise It's unusual to send the menu command to a inactive window.
